# Pascal procedure not writing how I expect

Tags: windows-8.1, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to create an installer using Inno Setup, which I have never used before, and everything is working fine, except that I'd like a VERSION.txt file to be created on installation.  Here's what I've got so far, at the very end of my script:

```
[Code]
procedure writeVersion();
begin
  SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\VERSION.txt'), '{#MyAppVersion}', False);
end;

procedure nowWrite();
begin
  writeVersion();
end;
```

But there is no VERSION.txt file being created at all after I compile and run the installer.  I've never used Pascal before, and this is as far as I could get before I gave up.  Why is the file not being created?

EDIT:
I tried adding

```
begin
  nowWrite();          
end.
```

to the end as suggested by @TLama, but it is still not writing a new file.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you calling your `nowWrite` procedure from somewhere ? P.S. `ExpandConstant` is not needed for the second parameter which only expands the preprocessor's variable.

Comment: As a debugging hint, check the expanded strings to see what they are.  Probably `writeln` can be used to examine an expression though it might be hard to figure out where the output can be seen.

Comment: It's not Pascal. You need to call it at some occassion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `noWrite` in an standard installer event. Currently your code is never called.

Supported events are listed [**on this page**](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents)

for example:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
    nowWrite();  
end;
```

will call your custom code when the setup's finished. Just study the documentation to choose the event which matches to your needs.